# How can I access/split/assign the (content) of 'body' from a rabbitmq message from within the pika callback function in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I am new to python and I am having a hard time getting my head around the following concept...

I have created some python code which imports Pika to connect and consume messages from a rabbitmq queue.

The basic code is shown below:

**receive.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pika

# RABBITMQ CONNECTION VARIABLES
MqHostName = 'centosserver'
MqUserName = 'guest'
MqPassWord = 'guest'
QueueName = 'Q1'

# PIKA CODE TO CONNECT TO RABBITMQ
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MqUserName, MqPassWord)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=MqHostName, credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=QueueName)

# CALLBACK ROUTINE TO RECEIVE MESSAGES FROM RABBITMQ
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

# DEFINE CALLBACK QUEUE
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=QueueName,
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

The above works in as much as the mq messages are printed as they are received however...

I would like to be able to consume the 'body' of the mq messages via my Python application. I have been able to do this in as much as I can assign the message body to a str variable and then use split to split the message into its component variables using a delimiter contained within each message (;) and then assign each one to a variable within my Python code, but I only seem to be able to do this within the callback function section of the code above...

If I then try and access/work with these variables from another python script - by importing from the receive.py script, I just get raw messages (or body) from the pika connection and I cant understand why this is...

The code I have developed so far is shown below:

```
import pika

# RABBITMQ CONNECTION VARIABLES
MqHostName = 'centosserver'
MqUserName = 'guest'
MqPassWord = 'guest'
QueueName = 'Q1'

# PIKA CODE TO CONNECT TO RABBITMQ
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(MqUserName, MqPassWord)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=MqHostName, credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(body) # this just prints what has been received from the queue with no formatting

    # create a string variable to hold the whole rabbit message body
    string_body = str(body)

    #split the string created above based on the message seporator enclosed in '' below
    message_vars = string_body.split(';')

    # define names for the variables which are seporated from the string_body in the step above and assign then to an array
    mv1, mv2, mv3, mv4, mv5, mv6, mv7, = \
    mq_vars[0], mq_vars[1], mq_vars[2], mq_vars[3], mq_vars[4], mq_vars[5], mq_vars[6]



# set the queue 
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

This allows me to print or perform operations on the mq1, mq2, etc... variables if I enter the code within the 'def callback(ch, method, properties, body):' block of code but I want to be able to have the receive script running and splitting the messages and assigning the content to global variables that I can access from another script by using an import statement.

Please can you point me in the right direction, basically I would like to be able to have a **process.py** script that will import just the values of mv1, mv2, etc... which will be updated each time a new MQ message is received...

**process.py**

```
from receive.py import mv1, mv2, mv3, mv4, mv5, mv6, mv7

new_var = (mv1 * mv2) # this is an example of what I would like to be able to do..
```

I know I don't yet understand enough about Python programming so there is likely to be an obvious answer to this but any pointers will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the `basic_publish` method which sends the data into the RabbitMQ.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard - I'm trying how to work out how to consume 'body' into my application so that I can work with the data 'body' contains - e.g if a message contains 'date;time;int;int;float - I want to split these using ';' and assign the values to variables so I can use them in another script or outside of the 'callback' function - I am able to do this within the CB function currently - if I import a var (e.g. mv1) from another script it seems to run the whole function and I get the full body of the msg even though I just tried to import mv1 from within the CB function of the receive script...